# Can the Map Location be Automatically Obtained Using Address, in Objective HTML's Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

We are using ObjectiveC's Google Maps module and fieldtype http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps, which allows a user to choose a location on a map to obtain the longitude and latitude which is saved to the entry (the longitude and latitude is used in search results for a "results near x miles" list).

Our users are already entering an address to display for the listing, so is it possible for the Google Maps add-on to automatically get the lat and long from the address so we do not have to offer the map for them to pick a location in addition to entering their address?

Comment: You should definitely be able to do this. Can you post an example of some template code? Also, are you using the search/results tags?

Comment: I am not sure template code will help. I am using a Safecracker form to enter an entry, the field is {field:location}, which is a Google Maps field, it shows this Module's Google Map to pick a location. I dont want to use this field, but I would like Google Maps to enter the long lat automatically when I create an entry from its address fields. So I dont have code that is not working, I just dont have any kind of code or setting that would allow this feature so wondered if it exists.

Comment: I've revised the question to make it a little more clear

Answer (score 1):

Ah, right. So I think you need Geocoder, which does exactly what you want. You can simply omit the Google Map field on the front-end, and have Geocoder plot the address for you after the form has submitted.

https://objectivehtml.com/geocoder

Comment: Aha! A different add-on by them! I did not think to look! I will give this a go and feedback, but sounds right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a different add-on but it's really an expansion pack to Google Maps for EE. It won't work unless you have Google Maps installed. ;)

Comment: I'd be interested to know the end result if you got this to work?